# iPhone app encryption issue while publishing to appstore

Tags: iphone, app-store, ipod

I have published an app to appstore which uses urbanairship. While publishing in the "Encryption" question "no" was selected, but I now find out using urbanairship we should say "yes" and select relevant type in the follow up screen.

1) I want to know how does it affect the app?

2) I am not receiving any push notifications, I am assuming that could be the reason, Am I correct?

3) Is there any way of changing this encryption without going through all the publishing steps again.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was issue with provisioning profiles, now I am getting the notifications.

Thanks

Comment: @Zapl The profiles got mixed up, and we were using development profile instead of distribution.